# VBA code needed for mandatory cell input based on if please

Tags: if-statement, range

I want to create a VBA macro which indicates the mandatory column to fill in based on a selected cell . Either Door or Either Airport.

https://ibb.co/coVNey

but if i Extend the range from (E3:E15) for instance i get run time error "13" Type mismatch.

Can anyone help and add it with the airport if statement?

So column E are the parameters either door or airport and F has to become mandatory when door has been indicated, G has to become mandatory when Airport has been selected.

thanks,

Comment: Please describe the question with the output you want.

Comment: Sorry so if in the E column " door " is chosen, the origin door location column must become mandatory cell input, if in column E " airport" is chosen, the Airport of departure column must become mandatory to fill in. The link above provides a screenshot.